# Max of Limited Query SOQL

Tags: soql, batch

I am trying to batch by date for large tables. I want to create batches of ~50000 records ordered by the LastModifiedDate. What I need is the MIN(LastModifiedDate) and MAX(LastModifiedDate) for each batch so I can create a query which will pull the next batch. There are some technology limitations which are outside the scope of this question. So basically, I would like to do this but in SOQL.

```
SELECT MAX(LastModifiedDate)
FROM (
  SELECT LastModifiedDate
  FROM leads
  WHERE LastModifiedDate >= MAX_of_previous_batch
  ORDER BY LastModifiedDate
  LIMIT 5000) foo
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a custom object which would have the fields like BatchId, No.of Records, No. of Success, No. of failures, Last Batch Run Datetime.

Now, when you run a batch you need to insert one record per batch in this custom object.

You should query your leads object for the records created just before the last batch run datetime of this custom object.

Hope this solution will work for you.

Comment: This is a good solution but it won't work well in my case. I will be pulling from a few schemas so I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require work on the Salesforce side. Plus the job will become a daily EL after the initial load and the batches will have changed. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: to control the batch size, custom settings is one option.

Comment: I'd suggest custom settings as well.